# Offsetting the rendered result of a camera in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, perspectivecamera

I am trying to make everything that is rendered by my perspective "Camera A" appear 100 points higher. This is due to the fact that my App has an interface with an open space on the upper part.

My app uses face detection to simulate the face movement into an in game avatar. To do this I compute the "Model-View-Matrix" to set it into the camera's "worldToCameraMatrix".

So far this works well, but everything is rendered with the center as the origin, now i want to move this center origin a certain distance "up" so that it matches my interface.

**Is there a way to tell Unity to offset the rendered camera result?**

An alternative I thought about is to render into a texture, then I can just move the texture itself, but I thought there must be an easier way.

---

By the way, my main camera is orthographic, and i use this one to render the camera texture. In this case simply moving the rendering game object quad up does the trick.

---

I found a property called "pixelRect", the description says:

> Where on the screen is the camera rendered in pixel coordinates.

However moving the center up seems to scale down my objects.

Comment: Not sure I get what you are trying to get but try changing the values in the Viewport rect of the camera component. Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: The viewport seems to change the scale of whats rendered. All i want is to make stuff appear higher on the screen (not on the 3d world)

Comment: yeh the [camera rect](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-rect.html) is not perfect because it doesn't extend beyound the actual screen area. You will just have to compensate for the scaling by adjusting the `orthographicSize` value of your camera. alternatively build in the offset adjustment into your computation for worldToCameraMatrix of like you say use a Texture

Comment: Infact that adjusting the orthographicSize doesn't help in the way you want. I have a feeling the only way you're going to get what you want is to adjust the camera's localPosition.y in LateUpdate

Answer (score 1):

You can set the viewport rect/orthosize so that its offset or you can render to a render texture and render that as a overlay with a offset or diffirence in scale.

Cheers